# Unable to post request , getting error- java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a REST method that will get the config file for a domain(Its in XML format and having more than 20K lines). 
While I am executing this Rest Call in Tomcat, I am getting following Error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:558)
at com.verizon.vzips.util.RestClientUtil.fetchDataFromServer(RestClientUtil.java:95)
at com.verizon.vzips.servlet.VZIPSServlet.doPost(VZIPSServlet.java:126)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.verizon.vzips.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following is the code for rest call :

```
@POST
    @Path("/updateConfigFiles")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response updateConfigFiles(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        super.request = req;
        logger.info("performing updateConfigFiles");
        DataSourceCriteria criteria = new DataSourceCriteria();
        setUserIdUserTypeToCriteria(req, criteria);
        final Status responseStatus = Status.OK;
        ConfigHolder configHolder=new ConfigHolder();
        String type = request.getParameter("type");
        //String configData = request.getParameter("order");

        //System.out.println(configData);

        configHolder.setOrderId(request.getParameter("order"));
        configHolder.setService(request.getParameter("service"));
        if ("Pre".equals(type)) {
            configHolder.setBootStrapConfig(request.getParameter("order"));
        } else {
            configHolder.setDomainConfig(request.getParameter("order"));
        }
        try{
        DBConnectionUtils.updateConfigFiles(configHolder);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in updateConfigFiles"
                + e.getMessage());
        final String errorMessage = processExceptions(e, userProfile);
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(errorMessage).build();
    }

    return Response
            .status(responseStatus)
            .build();

}
```

I have added `maxPostsize` and `maxHeadersize` into the `server.xml` and still getting the above error.

Is there any alternate solution / fix for this issue.
I have tried with all possible solution but didn't succeed.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: the error message is from the client side, the code is from the server side? And is the error message complete or did you cut the nested exceptions ("caused by ...")?

Comment: You are right @Codo

And this is the complete error.

Comment: Can you add your client side code that runs into the error?

Comment: If the server url is not correct or webservice is not accepting the post, this error can occur. Most likely check the path of service call or check any errors on Server end during startup.